# How to get ICH AC97 audio controller to work under Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, drivers, soundcard

I have installed Ubuntu Server 11.04 as a Virtual Box VM, which emulates the ICH AC97 audio controller.

mpg321 reports 'No default libao driver available'

According to [this page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man4/snd_ich.4freebsd.html) the driver for this device can be loaded at boot time by modifying 'loader.conf', but I cannot find any such file on the system

Is the file called something else, or is it something that I need to create from scratch?

Alternatively is there another way I can get the audio drivers installed?

I am getting the same problem with version 10 Server,  and also on a non VM machine with the same audio driver

**Solution:**

Install alsa-oss

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-oss
```

Add the user to the audio group

```
sudo adduser username audio
```

Log out and log in again

Finally run alsamixer and make sure that the master and PCM controls are not muted

Comment: Have you installed the VirtualBox guest additions?

Comment: Is that possible without building the linux kernel from scratch? In any case I get the same problem on a real machine with the same audio driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a good place to start http://wiki.debian.org/SoundFAQ they suggest trying to run the command with sudo.

I did this with mpg321 and it no longer complained about "can't find a suitable libao driver. is device in use" but still no sound from the Virtual Box VM. Same with mplayer, under normal user, runs under sudo but no sound.

Comment: From your link adding my user to the audio group after installing also-oss seems to have done the trick, thanks (no sound, but that might be a VM thing)

Comment: Run alsamixer and make sure that the master and pcm lines are not muted

Answer (score 2):

Install alsa-oss

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-oss
```

Add the user to the audio group

```
sudo adduser username audio
```

Log out and log in again

Finally run alsamixer and make sure that the master and PCM controls are not muted